# katello-agent for CentOS Stream 9?

Tags: centos, foreman

I am unable to find the `katello-agent` package for the new CentOS Stream 9. (I've even tried to install the repo for CentOS Stream 8, but it results in broken dependencies, as expected.) Is there a workaround to install it?

(I know that [Katello is deprecated](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/6.9/html-single/release_notes/index) in favour of Remote Execution, but for now I'll have to do with.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even the latest version of Foreman (v3.2) [doesn't support CentOS Stream 9](https://theforeman.org/manuals/3.2/index.html#2.Quickstart) and won't support it in the future. So the solution is either to enable Remote Execution on Foreman instead of the agent, or use another OS.

Answer (score 0):

I just received this message from the Foreman site:

Dirk
Packager
10h
Yes, it will be supported on CentOS Stream 9, but the software must be ready for the newer version of Ruby, NPM, NodeJS, … before packages can be created.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for the contribution. Can you provide a link to the exact site or post on the site where you got this information from?